# Using templates to avoid similar functions

Tags: c++, templates, code-maintainability

Lets say I have 2 functions which perform the exact same operations on the arguments but use different sets of constants to do so. For an oversimplified example:

```
int foo1(int x){
    return 3+4*x
}
int foo2(int x){
    return 6-4*x
}
```

In the real applications assume there will be multiple arguments and constants/literals, and of course the computation will be much more complex.
For the sake of simplicity, as well as maintainability, I want to rewrite these two functions as a template that can produce both of these functions, so that I could call foo<1> or foo<2> and the proper function will be generated. I am aware that I could do something like this:

```
int foo(int x, int funcType){
    const int firstConst = (funcType==1) ? 3 : 6;
    const int secondConst = (funcType==1) ? 4 : -4;
    return firstConst+secondConst*x;
}
```

but since I am always aware at compile time of which function I want to use, I would like to use templates to avoid the branching. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
templatr<int funcType>
void foo(int x){
  const int firstConst = (funcType==1) ? 3 : 6;
  const int secondConst = (funcType==1) ? 4 : -4;
  return firstConst+secondConst*x;
}
```

no compiler worth using under any non-zero optimization setting will have a runtime branch for the above template function.

And it is often easier to read than traits classes.

You can have fun with this technique in general, writing long branchy code that compiles down to tight operations.  This scales reasonably well if your code decomposes into pieces nicely (like `bool do_foo` as a template parameter).

Scaling beyond that you probably want to avoid maintaining a central list of numerical IDs.  Finding traits by tag dispatching to a constexpr ADL enabled traits function, or takijg a template non type pointer to constexpr struct, both can give you the zero overhead effect with distributed function sub type declaration.

Finally, you could just pass a traits class in directly:

```
template<class Traits>
void foo(int x){
  return x*Traits::z+Traits::y;
}
```

or

```
template<class Traits>
void foo(int x){
  return x*Traits{}.z+Traits{}.y;
}
```

or even

```
template<class Traits>
void foo(int x, Traits traits={}){
  return x*traits.z+traits.y;
}
```

depending on specific needs.

Comment: both answers were correct and the other one should work regardless of compiler settings, but this way is definitely easier to read.

Comment: But this won't scale well into more functions. Since we're talking about maintainability, I don't see why this is preferred over [songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679563/4832499)

Comment: @passer It depends how large they are and if they decompose naturally.  Amd even if they don't, I'd find template pointers to constexpr structs or ADL tag-dispatched traits functions more scalable than "call function `253`", even if just having to maintain IDs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a traits class template to manage constants/literals separately, e.g.

```
template <int FuncType>
struct Constants;

template <>
struct Constants<1> {
    static const int firstConst = 3;
    static const int secondConst = 4;
};

template <>
struct Constants<2> {
    static const int firstConst = 6;
    static const int secondConst = -4;
};

template <int FuncType>
int foo(int x){
    return Constants<FuncType>::firstConst + Constants<FuncType>::secondConst * x;
}
```

then call it as

```
foo<1>(42);
foo<2>(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the traits case, you can do:

```
template <int a, int b>
int foo(int x)
{
    return a * x + b;
}

int foo1(int x){
    return foo<4, 3>(x);
}

int foo2(int x){
    return foo<-4, 6>(x);
}
```

Comment: This wont scale well for a large number of constants but it could be simpler for smaller functions like in the example